# Reduced navbar; select and button on the same line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm using bootstrap and have the following problem. I have a select and a button in my navbar and want them on the same line when the navbar is reduced (width < 762).

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vuwovq9g/

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-form">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option value="">Alphabétique</option>
        <option value="">Modification</option>
        <option value="">Création</option>
    </select></div><button type='button' style="margin-top:10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></button>
```

When the navbar is small, the button is under the select. I tried to put the button inside the div but get a worse result (when the navbar is big, the button is under the select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/vuwovq9g/2/)

add `display:inline-block` to the div that contains your selectbox. This way the div will collapse its width so there is "room" for the button.